# Youtube Search API accuracy

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to make a simple script that searches youtube using it's v3 API, but for a specific keyword, I don't get the same videos as youtube.com .

This is the URL I am using: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=relevance&regionCode=US&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=test&key=*****`

Any ideas how accurate is the API compared with youtube.com ?

Answer (score 0):

API should be in the same accuracy as the website. Are you testing with same user account? Can you give some specific examples to follow up?

Comment: Your answer may be correct but ideally you should back it up with sources and link as much as possible. The above could easily be interpreted as one person's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing the search filter with other region with my code, because I'm in Argentina, and trying to get only 3 videos.

I have the same result with the API and in the YouTube page.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=3&order=relevance&q=test&regionCode=AR&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I get this response:

```
200 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"GGhQgtOz7wdV-KaTX3akpjqktXI/ZQcMULMzhl7jNZmXCsem5ycElvI\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 3
 },
 "nextPageToken": "CAMQAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "nCgQDjiotG0"
   },
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"GGhQgtOz7wdV-KaTX3akpjqktXI/4xgmXYRPkRjv8kxP_M5CKZQM2GM\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2010-05-04T00:49:30.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCL8ZULXASCc1I_oaOT0NaOQ",
    "title": "Google Chrome Speed Tests",
    "description": "These speed tests were filmed at actual web page rendering times. If you're interested in the technical details, read on! Equipment used ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nCgQDjiotG0/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nCgQDjiotG0/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nCgQDjiotG0/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "N7-T53_pOSM"
   },
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"GGhQgtOz7wdV-KaTX3akpjqktXI/T1_ucgK_momRYuuh8o4LvRpJHWM\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-10-03T21:40:01.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOmcA3f_RrH6b9NmcNa4tdg",
    "title": "Always On - Torture testing the iPhone 5 Ep 16",
    "description": "cnet.com The iPhone 5 enters the torture chamber, the Tesla S gets unboxed, the Galaxy S3 is thrown in the washing machine, and Molly Wood sets ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N7-T53_pOSM/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N7-T53_pOSM/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N7-T53_pOSM/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "ubNF9QNEQLA"
   },
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"GGhQgtOz7wdV-KaTX3akpjqktXI/NM08y0TtHGe2IYmzq8XNDhy6WhY\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2008-11-03T17:49:54.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCFsK_jxE6BghGx4d2QJLJzQ",
    "title": "Test Your Awareness : Whodunnit?",
    "description": "Test your Awareness with Do The Test's Whodunnit. Who Killed Lord Smithe? TFL cycling safety advert! How observant are you? How did you do? www ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ubNF9QNEQLA/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ubNF9QNEQLA/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ubNF9QNEQLA/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And in the YouTube page I get the same result:

```
Google Chrome Speed Tests
by Google Chrome•2 years ago•6,721,020 views
These speed tests were filmed at actual web page rendering times. If you're interested in the technical details, read on ...
HDCC
31:01  
Always On - Torture testing the iPhone 5 Ep 16
by CNETTV•4 months ago•267,084 views
Season 2•Episode 16•Always On
cnet.com The iPhone 5 enters the torture chamber, the Tesla S gets unboxed, the Galaxy S3 is thrown in the washing machine ...
HD
1:55  
Test Your Awareness : Whodunnit?
by dothetest•4 years ago•3,477,032 views
Test your Awareness with Do The Test's Whodunnit. Who Killed Lord Smithe? TFL cycling safety advert! How observant are you ...
HD
```

Comment: But when I try to retrieve 10 videos I get the same list with the API and in the YouTube page, but with different order ..